# What's the meaning of this phrase? "....exploded in our faces."

Tags: spoken-english

The conversation is below:

> Jason: Maggie. I tried to include you
>
> Maggie: Oh don't patronize me Jason throwing me a bone calling me old (expletive) maybe a few years you can bring me back for old timers day.
>
> Jason: We talked about all of this I just happen to be the guy who is here the day the whole gummy bear thing **exploded in our faces**.

So what's the meaning of exploded in our faces??

Comment: Please try to copy the dialogue carefully, including the punctuation if possible. Also, have you tried searching a dictionary ([explode in your face](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/explode+in+your+face))?

Comment: Of course I search it first, and then ask the question here! I couldn’t find the answer that’s why post the question here and wait for the answer! The dialogue is directly from the website, and I don’t understand why you are being so strick on this tiny stuff instead of answering people question. Well, if you don’t want to answer, it’s your public, but please be nice!

Answer (score 5):

The phrase **explode in our faces** there is a figurative, not a literal, expression.

Literally it means "to blow up (like a bomb) unexpectedly".  Figuratively, it means that the situation suddenly turned bad for you, in a manner that you had not anticipated.

> We introduced our new product to the market, but things blew up in our
>    faces when it was discovered to have a dangerous defect and had to be
>   taken off the shelves.